# Type to be defined as int on x86 and __int64 on x64, akin to size_t but signed?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Is there a signed integer type that is defined as `int` when compiled for `x86` and `__int64` when compiling for `x64` with Microsoft Visual Studio compiler? Akin to `size_t` but signed. Or do I need to define my own?

Comment: `uintptr_t` from `<stdint.h> ?

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Oh yeah. Thanks. `ptrdiff_t` it is. had a brain fart.... or maybe it's such a kloodgie abbreviation. As for `uintptr_t` -- that's the unsigned one. Should be `intptr_t` for signed.

Comment: I think VS defines `ssize_t`

Comment: `std::make_signed_t<std::size_t>`

Comment: The Win32 API also defines `SSIZE_T`.